# Can we use adverbs with comparative adjectives as in:

Tags: adverbs, comparative

> He is much taller than me.

Vs

> He is incredibly taller than me.

I know the first sentence is correct, but I was wondering if we could use Incredibly with a comparative adjective (taller).

Comment: It might pass muster in casual conversation, but it's not really grammatical in my opinion. I would prefer "He is incredibly tall - much taller than I am."

Comment: This was also asked on ELU.